# How to allow multiple users to access to the same crontab in Debian Linux v8.4?

Tags: linux, debian, cron, user-groups

I am trying to create a crontab for a group of users, lets call the group "testGroup". There are 3 users, and I want to give all of them access to the same crontab. I did some research and tried to add each individual user to the crontab group in the /etc/group file. This did not work however as there are still 3 separate crontabs for each user. Is this possible to fix? If so how would I go about doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Background

No, `cron` does not work the way you assume it does.

The `cron` daemon reads its crontabs from two places:

- System-wide `/etc/crontab`;
- Per-user crontabs.

There's no concept of per-group-of-users crontabs.

#### Solution

Debian has customized `cron` which allows to do what you need relatively easily.  To cite the `cron(8)` manual page:

> Additionally, in Debian, `cron` reads the  files in the `/etc/cron.d`  directory. cron treats the files in `/etc/cron.d` as in the same way as the `/etc/crontab` file (they follow the special format of that file, i.e. they include the user field). However, they are independent of `/etc/crontab`: they do not, for example, inherit environment variable settings from it. This change is specific to Debian see the note under **DEBIAN SPECIFIC** below.

Hence I would do the following:

1. Create a dedicated group for your group of users.  Let's assume it's "mycrontab".
2. Add your three users into that group.
3. Create a file under `/etc/cron.d` and make it be owned by `root:mycrontab`
   and has permission bits set to `0660` or `rw-rw-r--`, that is, read/write access to the user `root` and group `mycrontab` and read access to everyone else.
4. Teach your users about where to locate this file and the rules about its format (those could be placed in the file in the form of comments).

Note that you might need to figure out how to handle sending mails to all your users.  I'd check if it's OK to set the `MAILTO` environment variable obeyed by `cron` to a comma-separated list of e-mail addresses first (like `joe@domain.lan,jane@domain.lan,jill@domain.lan`) or, failing that, you'd probably need to set up a mail alias either in your local MTA or the MTA receiving mails generated by `cron` on your system, and use the value of this alias for the `MAILTO` variable.

All in all, please give the `cron(8)` and `crontab(5)` manual pages at least a cursory glance.

…and please remove your users from the `crontab` group!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how @kostix' solution does not allow to run code as root.

You're basically giving the root crontab access to users. It's very dangerous.

Personally, I would create a generic account with the same right as the users, and allow users to su - to that user and edit its crontab